# Cannot copy Macrium Reflect mrimg file using Windows command line

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive, robocopy, lock, macrium

I created full system backup of my Windows 10 PC using Macrium Reflect and it created a `.mrimg` file of around 400 GB. This file is stored on an external hard drive (HDD). I want to copy it to another disk.

If I drag-and-drop it, the copying works fine on the Windows 10 PC, but it takes very long (estimated time 5+ hours). So I thought of using **Robocopy** from command line in the hope it would be faster:

```
Robocopy G:\Folder\file.mrimg H:\
```

But it gives me an error message:

> "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."

I tried this from both, the usual command prompt and the Windows Powershell , but getting the same error. I did make sure the directory and file names are absolutely correct.

I am wondering if the `.mrimg` file gets sort of locked when Windows 10 is running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, as far as copying a single file, robocopy is not going to copy any faster. The file is going to transfer as fast as physically possible with the hardware you have and that’s it.

Next, your command line syntax for robocopy is wrong. Robocopy is not made for copying single files really. It’s made for mirroring entire directory structures. It does not function the same as `copy` or `xcopy`.

If you want to copy a single file then you need to specify it separately.

```
Robocopy G:\Folder H:\ file.mrimg
```

https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html